# Tapestry: How to write HTML from java page

Tags: html, tapestry, expansion

I need to write HTML from my .java page. Here is what I have tried

This is my tml code fragment

```
${testFunction()}
```

This is my java code fragment

```
public String testFunction()
{
   return "<input type='checkbox' name='leaf' id='leaf' value='leaf'/>"
}
```

The result I want is a checkbox. What I get is a string "input type='checkbox' name='leaf' id='leaf' value='leaf'". 
Any help would be appreciated Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to render string as html you need to use [MarkupWriter#writeRaw()](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/MarkupWriter.html#writeRaw%28java.lang.String%29) method:

```
void beginRender(MarkupWriter writer) {
  writer.writeRaw("<input type='checkbox' name='leaf' id='leaf' value='leaf'/>");
}
```

Or you can use [OutputRaw](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/OutputRaw.html) component:

```
<t:outputraw value="testFunction()"/>
```

Or you can use Renderable to write markup:

```
@Property(write = false)
private final Renderable checkbox = new Renderable() {
  public void render(MarkupWriter writer) {
    writer.element("input",
        "type", "checkbox",
        "id", "leaf",
        "name", "leaf",
        "value", "leaf");
    writer.end();

    // if you need checked attribute
    // writer.getElement().attribute("checked", "checked");
  }
};
```

And on template:

```
<t:delegate to="checkbox"/>
```